# trying to convert timestamp to time with data type as int

Tags: java, java-8, timestamp, timezone, java-time

Trying to convert timestamp to time with any zone using java, here I'm able to convert using ZoneID but it will return string data type. here I'm expecting output like getTimeMillis()

```
Instant now = Instant.ofEpochMilli(lngDate);
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");   

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
String zdt = zonedDateTime.format(isoDateFormatter);
```

Here I'm expecting only time millis (8-digits number) and below giving you my code can you please help to solve it.

Input : 1552979609000L

```
DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME;
String zdt = zonedDateTime.format(isoDateFormatter); // output in string : 00:13:29-07:00
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(zdt, isoDateFormatter); // output in local time : 00:13:29
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to convert?  “Timestamp” can mean many things.  Are you trying to convert an Instant?  A ZonedDateTime?  A java.sql.Timestamp?  A String?  A millisecond representation of a date-time is a long, so how are you expecting to fit it into an int?

Comment: Also, in general, one doesn't represent numeric timestamps in any other time zone than UTC.  There are some exceptions, but generally if I see a timestamp that is based on the Unix epoch, that epoch is UTC, so that timestamp is UTC.  Putting in some other time zone would be problematic to anyone I might give it to, as they would treat it as UTC.  In other words, you'd be picking a different point in time completely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the millisecond of the day, in other words, the count of milliseconds since 00:00:00 as in `int` from 0 (inclusive) to 86 400 000 (exclusive; up to 8 digits). The `ChronoField` enum has a constant for that, so it’s straightforward when you know how:

```
    int millisecondOfDay = zonedDateTime.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println("Millisecond of day: " + millisecondOfDay);
```

Output when running just now:

> Millisecond of day: 7773854

Comment: Thanks for your information. Here I'm expecting only time millis (8-digits number) and below giving you my code can you please help to solve it 
Input : 1552979609000L
DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME;
String zdt = zonedDateTime.format(isoDateFormatter); // output in string : 00:13:29-07:00
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(zdt, isoDateFormatter); // output in local time : 00:13:29

Comment: I think I understand now. I have rewritten the answer.